# Retrieving Json data from external URL

Tags: php

I'm having a hard time getting some json data from an API here. Basically I want to get the file contents, then assign the "meta_game" to a variable and I also want the "channel_count" to be assigned to a variable. As you can see here, I tried 2 different methods for both instances and neither work at the moment.

```
$json = file_get_contents($chan);
$json_data = unserialize($json);
$gameName = json_decode($json)->meta_game;
$viewerCount = $json_data['channel_count'];
```

Heres an example of a URL it would be taking this from: http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json?channel= + channel name.

Comment: Did you try running a dry test to see what you getting in return for the json_data variable?

Comment: I don't understand how you could possibly even state what you just said. How does asking a question on this website which was made for this be quoted as lazy? Clearly I couldn't reproduce what I was looking for which is why I came here.

Comment: "Here's my code. I won't care telling how it fails to meet my needs. Guess what's wrong and fix it."

Comment: Is there any other method to asking a question coming from the standpoint of a user who is not as literate in this language as you may be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you unserializing the data?  Its not required

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json?channel=' . $channelName);
$jsonData = json_decode($json);

$gameName = $jsonData->meta_game;

$viewerCount = $jsonData->channel_count;
```

Of course you may need to check the paths through the `$jsonData` object to find your final values as I didn't parse it and can't guarantee they are at the first node.

Update: Because I can't leave things alone, I checked this to see what the response from the API was

As it returns an array first, your paths will be

```
$jsonData[0]->channel->meta_game;

$jsonData[0]->channel_count;
```

Assuming you only have 1 channel in the response

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate the assistance.

Answer (score 1):

you can try below code

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json?channel=');
$gameName = json_decode($json,true);
$new_arr = array();
foreach($gameName as $g){
print_r( $g['channel']['meta_game']);
 array_push($new_arr,$g['channel']['meta_game']);
}    
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(function($){
    $.fn.fetch = function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
        //var optionsWithDefaults = $.extend(defaults, options);
        return this.each(function() {
            var obj = [];
            $.getJSON(' http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json?channel=xxx',
                function(data) {
                    $.each(data, function(i, feed) {
                        if(feed.channel_count !== undefined) {
                            obj.push(feed.channel_count);
                        }
                    });
                }
            );
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```